# OIDC client not routing to login page when in Azure instance environment

Tags: reactjs, azure, docker, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm setting up a front end application to use OIDC login with [oidc-client-ts](https://github.com/authts/oidc-client-ts), and [react-oidc-context](https://github.com/authts/react-oidc-context), with keycloak acting as my OAuth Provider.  I set up the auth wrapper like this in my react UI app:

```js
// App.tsx

const oidcConfig: AuthProviderProps = {
  authority: `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}:9090/realms/master`,
  client_id: "my_client",
  redirect_uri: window.location.href,
  onSigninCallback: () => {
    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.origin);
  },
  userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
  post_logout_redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider {...oidcConfig}>
      <div>App here</div>
    </AuthProvider>
  )
}

// Login.ts

export const LoginButton = () => {
  const { signinRedirect } = useAuth();

  return (
    <button onClick={() => signinRedirect()}>Login</button>
  )
}
```

I have a docker-compose which orchestrates my UI, Keycloak, and supporting apps:

```yaml
services:
  keycloak_iam:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    command: start-dev --http-port 9090 --health-enabled=true
    environment:
      SOME_ENV_VARS: stuff

  ui:
    build: .
    image: ui
    ports:
      - 80:3001
    command: npm start
```

Running `docker compose up` runs the stack, and locally, everything works.  In the UI, the user clicks the login button.  A call is made to `http://localhost:9090/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration`, and then the user is immediately redirected to `http://localhost:9090/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?bunch_of_params=stuff`.  They log in, and are redirected back to the app which was specified in `redirect_uri`, and the JWT gets saved in the auth state.

I have launched this whole docker-compose within an Azure linux instance.  After ensuring that ports 80 and 9090 are exposed, I can access the UI at instance IP X.X.X.X.  I can also go to X.X.X.X:9090, which takes me to the keycloak admin ui.

However, in the app running in my instance, clicking the login button does *not* redirect to the keycloak login page.  It does make the call to `http://X.X.X.X:9090/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration`, but no redirect happens.  If I click the login button again, no extra call is made, but no redirect happens.

What is going wrong here?  Why is the OAuth redirect flow working correctly on my local, but not in an azure instance?  I have done something similar in an openstack instance, also with no issue.  Could it be related to some azure instance setting? There are no errors or warnings in the console, I don't even know where to begin debugging this.